# Unable to search through an array to return the key code pressed

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to search through an array and that I've already made up. For reference:

```
var words = [
  "low tide",
  "kayak",
  "coral",
  "boat",
  "beachball",
  "hermit crab",
  "sunscreen"
];

//and then ive generated an underscore already to show up on the screen `
function generateUnderscore() {
    for (let i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i++) {
        underScore.push("_");
    }
    return underScore;
}
```

Now I'm trying to document the keycode that's pressed using `console.log()` so that I may keep track of my mistakes. However this code isn't working for some reason.

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    let keyword = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    if (chosenWord.indexOf(keyword) > -1) {
        rightWordArray.push(keyword);
        console.log(rightWordArray);
    }
});
```

Every time I use `console.log` or if I write an else statement into another array it only logs the keycodes into the `wrongLetterArray`.

Comment: sorry if code isn't formatted correctly

Comment: The callback that you add to the `keyup` event needs to take the event as an argument

Answer (score 0):

i've figured it out. so if i console log any of the characters it ends up being uppercase. Edna was right in the answer however it shouldn't be `.toLocaleLowerCase` it should be `toLowerCase` for some reason everytime i logged a key in console it was uppercase. No Caps Lock wasn't on. i'm not sure if it has something to do with a built in uppercase in javascript or what. but it worked. so ship it.

Answer (score -2):

If you console.log the keyword inside of your event listener, you should be able to get the key pressed. The reason why your if statement is not working is because the indexOf method is for arrays and the chosenWord I'm assuming is a string, if you're not using it on an array, it is going to return -1. 
A better method to use would be charAt, which is for strings, so you can change your if statement to

```
if (chosenWord.charAt(keyword.toLocaleLowerCase)) {
   rightWordArray.push(keyword);
   console.log(rightWordArray);
}
```

and it should run.